# Cloud9 - is there a way to use ssh workspaces with standalone?

Tags: docker, ssh, cloud9

I am running Cloud9 + Docker combination locally to keep up with a bunch of small projects. This whole zoo is sitting on my laptop and travels with me. I chose to run the infrastructure locally because I travel a lot and cloud IDE is not fun when you are on a crappy wireless connection or roaming in EU ;-)

Typically I have a docker image with Cloud9 + appropriate stack and I run container per project.

The way Cloud9 SDK is being installed is something along these lines:

```
git clone git://github.com/c9/core.git c9sdk --depth 1
cd c9sdk
./scripts/install-sdk.sh
./server.js -p 5000 --listen 0.0.0.0 -a : -w ~/src/${project-name}
```

A mild inconvenience is that I have Cloud9 instances sitting all over the place.

**Question**: I wonder if there is a way to run the server.js to use ssh workspace from another machine / docker container? I know this can be done in online version.

**Some hints**: I grepped through the sources a bit and it looks like the right way to do it is to create a custom client-workspace file with proper configs for c9.vfs.XXXX and then to run Cloud9 with --workspacetype option. But I just can't figure out how to set up the plugins to make Cloud9 run things over SSH as opposed to locally. I think I don't even need SSHFS for now because I can mount volumes with source code through docker.